# Converting one TypeScript type to a similar type

Tags: typescript

I have two interfaces that reflect what an API returns and what the data actually is

```js
interface APIModelCommon {
    id: number
    createdAt: string
    updatedAt: string
}

interface ModelCommon {
    id: number
    createdAt: Date
    updatedAt: Date
}
```

I want to write a function that converts the returned API model to the proper type. Previously, I've been forcing type assertions to fix this and that's required some `eslint-disable` comments, but I would like to handle this properly.

The function would be needed to convert `interface APIArchive extends APIModelCommon` to `interface Archive extends ModelCommon`, for example.

Everything I've tried thus far has given some sort of error and I've been unable to find my way around it.

```js
function correctScrapedModel<A extends APIModelCommon, T extends ModelCommon>(apiModel: A): T {
    const clone: T = (({ createdAt: _, updatedAt: __, ...o }) => ({
        ...o,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        updatedAt: new Date(),
    }))(apiModel)
    clone.createdAt = new Date(apiModel.createdAt)
    clone.updatedAt = new Date(apiModel.updatedAt)
    return clone
}
```

That's the function I'm currently at but it has the following error:

> TS2322: Type 'Omit<A, "createdAt" | "updatedAt"> & { createdAt: Date; updatedAt: Date; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.   'Omit<A, "createdAt" | "updatedAt"> & { createdAt: Date; updatedAt: Date; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'ModelCommon'.

I'm technically able to fix it with this:

```js
function correctScrapedModel<A extends APIModelCommon, T extends ModelCommon>(apiModel: A): T {
    const clone = (({ createdAt: _, updatedAt: __, ...o }) => ({
        ...o,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        updatedAt: new Date(),
    } as unknown as T))(apiModel)
    clone.createdAt = new Date(apiModel.createdAt)
    clone.updatedAt = new Date(apiModel.updatedAt)
    return clone
}
```

but I'm generally not a fan of `as unknown as TYPE` statements and would like to avoid it if possible.

Are there any better ways to achieve this? If there was someway of telling Typescript that `Omit<APIModelCommon, 'createdAt' | 'updatedAt'> & { createdAt: Date, updatedAt: Date}` is equivalent to `ModelCommon`, I think that'd be the way to solve it but I'm not aware of anyway to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to keep it [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

In the conditional branches where the generic is `"Json"` use JSON-compatible types (e.g. `string`), and in the branches where it's `"Native"`, use the desired native types (e.g. `Date`). You can even use a [default generic parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to make it less verbose for one of the variations (e.g. for the native types). Here's an example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhBOBLAhgG0QL2cRB7AdgGK7wC22UAvFAEQBy2iAbhDVAD60BSAzgTQG4AUENCQoAWVwATCKgDCuUqQIAeYmQoQAHsAj5pPWAhTosOAhvLAqtBjhY0AfLYDeQqFETSAXFHwArqQARgjCngDG8BDYENIAgsB+Vlq6+oZ2jI5QAPxQACKxUH48wEj4AObhUAFg0rEJSVApNjp6Bkb0Way5BUUlZYiVwgC+wkIAZgH4ERb4ULI8JmiYEFKyqAAUQ2ABTetyispqNLz8TgCUfgcKSirz7p7RwAHwDx6eXr5e+LvAAHTeAA0H0i0QaiT8+AgAHc+nptr89v8ojE9I0LiDPjU6hCmtC4YUETtkbV6ujEpiPmMhCMRFMZnMoEskCsMGsZHJEX9rpzbsd8FdJHyjvdVKc+PhnFBHlBnq93tjvH4SQDgaCoKi8SqkQCtRSAcBcABJGAAeRgg0qmyp2LJ2p+f3+9oN-yNpotVoqNqxUBpdKAA)

```ts
type SerializationFormat = "Native" | "Json";

type ModelCommon<Format extends SerializationFormat = "Native"> = {
  id: number;
  createdAt: Format extends "Native" ? Date : string;
  updatedAt: Format extends "Native" ? Date : string;
};

function deserializeModel(input: ModelCommon<"Json">): ModelCommon {
  return {
    id: input.id,
    createdAt: new Date(input.createdAt),
    updatedAt: new Date(input.updatedAt),
  };
}

function serializeModel(input: ModelCommon): ModelCommon<"Json"> {
  return {
    id: input.id,
    createdAt: input.createdAt.toISOString(),
    updatedAt: input.updatedAt.toISOString(),
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I made some edits (such as using generics on the function just so its obvious to me at a glance) but otherwise this works nicely. I would link to a TS Playground with what I ended up with but the link is massive.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are having is essentially due to the fact that there is no type shared between APIArchive and Archive (or any generic candidates extending APIModelCommon and ModelCommon)

```
interface APIArchive extends APIModelCommon {
    foo: string;
}

interface Archive extends ModelCommon {
    foo: string;
}
```

With the constraint defined on the method

```
<A extends APIModelCommon, T extends ModelCommon>
```

Typescript does not know that `type A` is supposed to equal `type T` once you omitted "createdAt" and "updatedAt".

I suggest that you are reworking your models so they can share attributes. But in the meantime, one easy way to work around it is to let type inference on the return type.

```
interface APIModelCommon {
  id: number;
  createdAt: string;
  updatedAt: string;
}

interface ModelCommon {
  id: number;
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date;
}

interface APIArchive extends APIModelCommon {
  foo: string;
}

interface Archive extends ModelCommon {
  foo: string;
}

function correctScrapedModel<A extends APIModelCommon, T extends ModelCommon>({
  createdAt,
  updatedAt,
  ...o
}: A &
  Omit<T, "createdAt" | "updatedAt">) {
  return {
    ...o,
    createdAt: new Date(createdAt),
    updatedAt: new Date(updatedAt),
  };
}

const a : APIArchive = {} as any; //trick compiler, real value not important here
const b : Archive = {} as any; //trick compiler, real value not important here

const c : Archive = correctScrapedModel(a);
```

Comment: The point of this question was how to do it without tricking the compiler because that's what I had initially with `as unknown as T`.

Comment: The compiler isn't tricked here (no any, no unknown). You can remove const a, b & c, they were just here to prove that correctScrapedModel is typed properly, but I see it was confusing